# How to get index in list

Tags: python, python-3.7

How would I check to see if the value is found and print the syntax? I have all my code done, but my problem is that I need to go locate where the value is located in the list. The problem is at the end of the code. I put #blank in those to areas because I do not know what to put there.

**Here is my code:**

```
list_of_scores = []

count = 0

for i in range(10):

    grade = int(input("Enter a quiz score "))
    list_of_scores.append(grade)

for grade in list_of_scores:

    while(count < 10):
        print("The score at position[", count, "] = ", list_of_scores[count])
        count = count + 1

search_value = (int(input("Enter a number to search for: ")))
```

***Below this is where I am having trouble. The top portion of my code is how it should be:

```
while(count < len(list_of_scores)):
    if(search_value) in list_of_scores:
        print("The value of ", search_value, "is in the list at index",#blank)
    else:
        if search_value not in list_of_scores:
            print(input("Sorry, this value isn't found. Please enter a new number:"))

print("The location of this value is: ", list_of_scores)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `index()` to get the index of item in list

```
print("The value of ", search_value, "is in the list at index",list_of_scores.index(search_value))
```